# Verify if the uploading file is as same as the downloaded file

Tags: java, file-comparison, filecompare

In java is there a way to verify if the user uploading file is as same as the one he just downloaded (other than by using the file name).

*For an example, **if the user is given a certain template to download and fill, and then upload the same, How can we verify if he is uploading the same file as he downloaded.***

Comment: Im aslo having the same issue with yet again a java web application. Where I have to give access to download more than one file and need to check if each uploading file is as same as the downloaded once

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that content of file is the same, just verify that checksum has not change e.g. [FileUtils.checksumCRC32](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#checksumCRC32(java.io.File))